# Laravel : How to Pass an attribute to Eloquent model constructor

Tags: laravel

I want to use strtolower() before saving data in database for 5 attributes,

I'm using this code in Model

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['firstName'] = strtolower($value);
}
public function setLastNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['lastName'] = strtolower($value);
}
public function setUserNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['userName'] = strtolower($value);
}
... etc
```

Can I use the __construct method instead of the above code?

Comment: You can use your model's boot method and override saving event.

Comment: first build a trait, then you can use model's boot method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways first one, to use boot method directly (preferred for small changes in model like in your question)


**Method 1 :**
we can directly use the boot method,

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Mymodel extends Model
{

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($model) {
                // Remember that $model here is an instance of MyModel
                $model->firstName = strtolower($model->firstName);
                $model->lastName = strtolower($model->lastName);
                $model->userName = strtolower($model->userName);
                // ...... other attributes
        });
    }
}
```

**Method 2 :**
So we can use here a simple trait with a simple method for generating a strtolower() for a string.This is preferred when you have to do bigger changes in your model while performing operations in model like saving, creating etc. Or even if you want to use the same property in multiple models.

Create a trait MyStrtolower

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;

trait MyStrtolower
{
    public function mystrtolower($string)
    {
        return strtolower($string);
    }
}
```

We can now attach this trait to any class that we want to have the mystrtolower method.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\MyStrtolower;

class Mymodel extends Model
{
    use MyStrtolower; // Attach the MyStrtolower trait to the model
 
    public static function boot()
    { 
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($model) {
                // Remember that $model here is an instance of MyModel
                $model->firstName = $model->mystrtolower($model->firstName);
                $model->lastName = $model->mystrtolower($model->lastName);
                $model->userName = $model->mystrtolower($model->userName);
                // ...... other attributes
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to not repeat all these lines of code for every model you make, make the trait configurable using abstract methods so that you can dynamically pass the attribute names for which you want to lower case string, like `employee_name` is `Employee` Model and `user_name` in `User` Model.

Comment: I'm using Method 1  in User Model But it gives an error
 Undefined index: App\Models\User .

Comment: I added this line to the code === parent::boot(); === But it gives an error ->  Call to undefined method App\Models\User::strtolower()

Comment: edited it , my bad actually wrote method 2 first then used it in method 1 try again now it will work